# How to use wide string literals in c++ without putting L in front of each one

Tags: c++, string, literals

You'll have to forgive my ignorance, but I'm not used to using wide character sets in c++, but is there a way that I can use wide string literals in c++ without putting an L in front of each literal?

If so, how?

Comment: ~14 years later, and this still seems to be a problem...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, there isn't. You have to use the L prefix (or a macro such as _T() with VC++ that expands to L anyway when compiled for Unicode).

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. the _T() macro only expands to L in you define UNICODE. that is essentially the point of having it as a macro. if you want the string to always be unicode just use L directly.

Answer (score 18):

The new C++0x Standard defines another way of doing this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#New_string_literals

Comment: Yeah, but that still requires a prefix.  BTW, I still voted you up because this is accurate advice.

Answer (score 3):

on a related note..
i'm trying to do the following

```
#define  get_switch( m )   myclass::getSwitch(L##m)
```

which is a macro the will expand

```
get_switch(isrunning)
```

into

```
myclass::getswitch(L"isrunning")
```

this works fine in c++ visualstudio 2008

but when i compile the same code under mac Xcode (for iphone) i get the error:

```
error: 'L' was not defined in this scope.
```

EDIT: Solution

```
#define  get_switch( m )   myclass::getSwitch(L ## #m)
```

this works on both vc++ and mac xcode (gcc)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `#define get_switch( m ) myclass::getSwitch(L ## #m)'?

Comment: thanks that does indeed work.. i had got it to work with myclass::getSwitch(L"" #m)  also

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not want to prefix string literals with an L?  It's quite simple - strings without an L are ANSI strings (`const char*`), strings with an L are wide-character strings (`const wchar_t*`).  There is the `TEXT()` macro, which makes a string literal into an ANSI or a wide-character string depending on of the current project is set to use Uncode:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define TEXT(s) L ## s
#else
#define TEXT(s) s
#endif
```

There's also the `_T()` macro, which is equivalent to `TEXT()`.

Comment: We're reading in files that may be in unicode and outputting a unicode xml, so the conversion mapping that we are doing internally compares a wstring to our string literal.

Comment: @Adam--just curious--do you know if the _T and TEXT macros are part of the language standard or are they MS VC++ specific?

Comment: It's in WinNT.h (included from windows.h). I wouldn't consider it as VC++ specific, but rather windows specific as it would be available in any setup that let you build WinAPI apps.